# Discord.js Can't ban member by message author

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want the bot to ban member.

Code:

```
  let member = message.guild.members.get(message.author);
  if(message.content === message.content && message.channel.id === id)
    member.ban("reason")
    message.channel.send("x")
```

So basically, whenever member sends message in specified channel, he will get ban. However, it does not ban. I tried to do it like `message.author.id` and so on but not successfully. Also, as I said it does not ban the member, but it sends the `"x"` message to the channel. I want to fix the ban problem and that it would send the `"x"` message as soon as he gets ban.

Answer (score 0):

1. `<GuildMemberManager>.get` doesn't exist. You should use its `fetch` method, that returns a `<GuildMember>` that you can ban using its `ban` method. This method returns a Promise so you need to `await` it. So replace `let member = message.guild.members.get(message.author);` with `let member = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);`
2. The expression `message.content === message.content` shouldn't be a condition as it always returns true.

```js
  let member = await message.guild.members.fetch(message.author.id);

  if(message.channel.id === id)
    member.ban("reason")
    message.channel.send("x")
```

Also don't forget to handle the `Promise` rejection of the `fetch`, `ban` and `send` methods.

Comment: It says `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.members.fetch is not a function`

Comment: What version of Discord.JS are you on? @MattThhh

Comment: 11.5.1. I downgraded because I had to rewrite bot fully and I didn't understand newer version that much.

Comment: V13 isn't hard. I would say give it a try because it is unlikely someone will be able to help you on such an old version, that doesn't even have documentation available online. Try starting [here](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin).